# Single-element version of the Replacement Theorem.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Show that for each pair of bases $B$ and $B'$ of a finite-dimensional vector space $V$, there is a bijection $\phi: B-B' \rightarrow B'-B$ so that for each $x\in B-B'$, the set $\{B-\{x\}\}\cup\{\phi(x)\}$ is a basis of $V$. (Hint: use Hall's theorem in graph theory).

I can prove this using other machinery. But I couldn't see how to use Hall's theorem to prove that $\{B-\{x\}\}\cup\{\phi(x)\}$ is a basis of $V$

Comment: Regarding the title: what makes you say this is an *easier* version of the replacement theorem? If anything, the result feels stronger, since it gives a kind of “simultaneous” replacement (not a very good name either). I think we might have to come up with a more appropriate title for the question, so that it can be found more easily in the future. :-)

Comment: @JossevanDobbendeBruyn The title is based on my understanding that the replacement theorem focuses on replacing a set of elements of the basis, whereas our problem focuses on replacing one single element of the basis. But I see your point.

Answer (score 1):

Hall's marriage theorem is useful when we have to find not just *any* bijection between two (finite) sets of equal size, but a bijection that satisfies some additional criteria. In this case, the extra criterion is that $\big(B \setminus \{x\}\big) \cup \{\phi(x)\}$ must again be a basis of $V$ for every $x \in B\setminus B'$.

Hence we construct a bipartite graph on the parts $L := B \setminus B'$ and $R := B' \setminus B$, where we have an edge between vertices $l \in L$ and $r \in R$ if and only if $\big(B \setminus \{l\}\big) \cup \{r\}$ is a basis of $V$. A perfect matching in this graph gives us the desired bijection. Conversely, a bijection that meets the requirements corresponds with a perfect matching in the graph.

Now all that remains is to show that a perfect matching exists. Luckily we have an easy way to check this: we simply see if the graph meets Hall's condition. Specifically, we have to check that any vertex set $S \subseteq L$ has at least $|S|$ neighbours in $R$. This is the exercise; I'll leave this part to you. (Do let me know if you need more help!)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. To verify Hall's condition, I assume by contradiction that there is a set $S\subseteq L$ that has less that $|S|$ neighbors in $R$. Then there exist $l_{1}, l_{2}\in L$ and $r\in R$ such that $\{ B-\{l_{1},l_{2}\}\}\cup\{r,r\}$ is a basis, which is impossible. So Hall's condition is satisfied. Does this seem right?